# How to move icons on Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, icons, kde, desktop-environments, .desktop

I'm new to Linux world. Recently I've installed Kubuntu and I don't know how to move icons on the desktop. When I drag an icon from applications (start menu) and drop it, I can't move it anymore. For example, if I drop it in the middle of desktop, I can't drag it to left corner. Seems like icons are locked. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean "can't move it anymore"? What happens when you try to move it? Did this used to work for you?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 3):

`Right Click` at the Desktop, `Unlock Widgets`. Or `Lock Widgets`, and then `Unlock Widgets` back again.

Then Pull not by the icon itself but by its little horizontal panel.

See at the picture:

[image]

Comment: Why oh why do you need to unlock this??? Just remove the lock / unlock function, it is totally useless and unecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Desktop.
Select "Enter edit mode".
Now you can move or resize the icons as you wish.

After you moved your icons, exit edit mode.