# How to show files in desktop in KDE 5 like file explorer?

Tags: kubuntu, files, .desktop, kde5

With cinnamon, gnome or in windows, we can put files on desktop as it like in file explorer. How can I do this in kubuntu with KDE5?

Comment: Please, could you be clearer? Do you wanna create desktop icons or move files from Documents folder to Desktop, for example?

Comment: Pardon me for my bad english ...
What I want to do is move files to Desktop and show it in the desktop. And treat it like file explorer. Like, you can copy and paste file to desktop in gnome, cinnamon or in windows.

Comment: It's OK, buddy. No problems with the english. Take a look in this question and see if can help you: http://askubuntu.com/q/483560/164660

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a **Folder View** widget to your desktop.

To do this:

- Right click on your desktop and select "**Add Widgets**".
- Look for the "**Folder View**" widget and drag it to your desktop, it should default to your `/home/user/Desktop` folder.